# Retrieving item from AlertDialog to Activity from a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm working on an android app and my requirement is that, I need to display the cursor values into alertdialog and let the user choose an item from the list and the value selected should be returned to the calling Activity.In my app, based on the student info, the cursor holds the values of courses he is taking. So the user should be able to choose one of the courses and then that value should be returned to the Activity that called alertdialog. Can you please let me know how to proceed on this.I've looked at multiple examples and none seems to work exactly.
Here is my sample code

```
   final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());  
   final Cursor courses=dbConnector.getCourses(student);
   builder.setTitle("Enter Course");
   builder.setCursor(courses, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int itemSelected) {
       if (courses.moveToPosition(itemSelected)) {
           String text=courses.getString(0);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 "You selected: "+text,                                  
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           builder.show();
      }
      courses.moveToFirst();
   }
 },"course");
builder.create();
createRow(sview, student, pass,text);
```

Now I want to return the text variable to the Calling Activity but, here it is local to the onClick() method. How can we do that without having to extend any DialogFragment class.

Comment: NOTE: this is  a part code of a big java file so, I just gave the code corresponding to the AlertDialog.

Comment: create custom listview add cursor into that and `builder.setView(listView)` will work. And attach listener to listview to accomplish your flow

Comment: Can you please point me to such an example ..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you calling a method of the class inside overridden onClick method and do whatever you like with that because the method will be in the `Activity` like here

```
@Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int itemSelected) {
    myMethod(itemSelected);
}

private void myMethod(int selectedItem){
  //Do whatever with that selected item
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried that, but I'm not sure, how to use the text  variable outside the function.   I want to use this function which uses text variable as one of the parameters along with other parameters which are only known in the activity and are not passed to the AlertDialog.How do we tackle in that case?? createRow(sview, student, pass,text);

Comment: There will be one `List` or `ArrayList` variable which will be currently holding the data you need. Create that variable in class level or make global And show that list in `Dialog`. Then after selecting one item `myMethod` is called with the position of `selectedItem`. You can retrieve the specific item of list by using that index like.. `myList.get(selectedItem)`